# Simple Python POST urlencode()

Tags: python, python-module

I'm trying to send a POST to my Node.js app using Python. Here is my code

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = my_url
values = {'email' : my_email,
      'password' : my_password }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)

req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print(the_page)
```

The request is sent, but somehow the parameters are getting messed up because the response I am getting corresponds to invalid login credentials.

I can do this same request using Postman for Chrome and it works just fine. So I know it's not something with my API.

So essentially I can do GET requests just fine with Python but for some reason, when I try to include parameters in a POST they are not translated correctly.

I've already looked through the docs for urllib, urllib2 and urlencode(). I could not find anything helpful

Comment: Is your API using any kind of session cookies? Your usage of the `urllib2` library is otherwise perfectly fine, so it is something else that is missing here.

Comment: Is your API using the same `user-agent` as browser ?

Comment: It's set up with Passport so there is a session cookie for the logged in user. I'ts just using the standard serializeUser and deserializeUser functions. So do I need special headers for my Python POST?

Comment: @user3783608: you'll need to issue a `GET` first and preserve the cookie that sets, probably, yes.

Comment: @user3783608: this task would be far easier using the `requests` library (with a session).

Comment: @user3783608: See [Making HTTP POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3659595) for the (involved) method to handle cookies between requests when using `urllib2`.

Comment: I just used the `requests` library, everything's working fine. I just needed to do a quick, one-time bulk POST, so I was getting frustrated at how long it was taking. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

I do no longer debug urllib2 problems, since I switched to requests, I do no longer have them, you may do so:

```
import requests

print requests.post(my_url, data={'email': my_email, 'password': my_password}).text
```

So readable, so elegant...
If your jquery app returns json, you may use ".json()" instead of ".text"

Your problem seems to have to keep cookies, to do so, you may just use a [requests session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)